# Rails routes multiple optional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a question, how can you make multiple optional params. F.e. in my variant, I need similar thing to "/(:first_name || :last_name || middle_name || all_names)". How can I achieve and can I achieve such thing in routes?

Btw, it'd be nice if I can do a lot of multiple params f.e.:

`/(:a || :b || :c)/(:d || :e)/(:n || :m)`

Thanks for answering.

Comment: You can't possible do this - how is server to tell whether given params represents first name or last name? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I need different urls for different queries.

Comment: Still not clear, what you are trying to achieve, usually every site wants different urls for different queries. Question is how you'l; lus those params in your controller.

Comment: I have one controller in which I filter params, in current state I have only lots of gets for same controller and now I need multiple urls for same controller just for different queries. Second you have just bunch of links in which you merge params to achieve one big query and for that query I need to show url name, not like /names?first_name=...

Comment: Ok example: `user/john/`. Is John first or middle name? The best you can do: `user/first_name/john` with `user(/first_name/:first_name)(/middle_name/:middle_name)` bot it is not much prettier than GET params

Comment: So it'll look like '`/(/first_name/:first_name)(/middle_name/:middle_name)'` ? :)

Comment: Without the `/` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks :) If you want, post an answer, I'll rate it :)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to do all the conditional work in the *controller* - the *routes* are there to capture request URLs & direct them to specific functionality (controller/actions).

Thus, your question of using

`/(:a || :b || :c)/(:d || :e)/(:n || :m)`

... is fundamentally flawed (you can't have condition "or" in Routes).

---

What you *can* have is [*bound parameters*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters):

[image]

These are optional params which a route *can* take, but doesn't have to.

In your case, you'll need to use them to denote the name as passed:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "" do
   get :first_name(/:middle_name(/:last_name)), action: :show, on: :collection
end
```

This is the best you're going to get without doing something custom in the routing system... like having `slugs` or something.

Comment: The optional parameters needs the `/`? can be without it? for example `/my-:param(-can-be-:optional)(-and-this-:too)`

Comment: I think only with `/` although you'll need to test to find out

Comment: Is this `:first_name(/:middle_name(/:last_name))` a valid Ruby syntax?

Comment: Thanks for this. I just did a really sick feature thanks to this post and some query objects.